# Estimating pairwise distance for large daraset using sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances or scipy.spatial.distance.cdist

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

I am trying to estimate pairwise distances between features for a dataset of ~300,000 images to a subset of the data for computing their minimums. However, the computed distance matrix is too large to fit in memory, causing OOM error.

For context, I am trying to implement the kcenter_greedy approach to active learning like given here (https://github.com/google/active-learning/blob/master/sampling_methods/kcenter_greedy.py)

Most academic datasets people have evaluated this on are small and hence the code works fine. In my case, I would like to work with a larger dataset for which the `sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances` function is not as useful.

Here is the relevant section of the code

```
def update_distances(self, cluster_centers, only_new=True, reset_dist=False):
    """Update min distances given cluster centers.
    Args:
      cluster_centers: indices of cluster centers
      only_new: only calculate distance for newly selected points and update
        min_distances.
      rest_dist: whether to reset min_distances.
    """

    if reset_dist:
      self.min_distances = None
    if only_new:
      cluster_centers = [d for d in cluster_centers
                         if d not in self.already_selected]
    if cluster_centers:
      # Update min_distances for all examples given new cluster center.
      x = self.features[cluster_centers]
      ################ This is the section causing OOM issues######################################
      dist = pairwise_distances(self.features, x, metric=self.metric)

      if self.min_distances is None:
        self.min_distances = np.min(dist, axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
      else:
        self.min_distances = np.minimum(self.min_distances, dist)

  def select_batch_(self, model, already_selected, N, **kwargs):
    """
    Diversity promoting active learning method that greedily forms a batch
    to minimize the maximum distance to a cluster center among all unlabeled
    datapoints.
    Args:
      model: model with scikit-like API with decision_function implemented
      already_selected: index of datapoints already selected
      N: batch size
    Returns:
      indices of points selected to minimize distance to cluster centers
    """

    try:
      # Assumes that the transform function takes in original data and not
      # flattened data.
      print('Getting transformed features...')
      self.features = model.transform(self.X)
      print('Calculating distances...')
      self.update_distances(already_selected, only_new=False, reset_dist=True)
    except:
      print('Using flat_X as features.')
      self.update_distances(already_selected, only_new=True, reset_dist=False)

    new_batch = []

    for _ in range(N):
      if self.already_selected is None:
        # Initialize centers with a randomly selected datapoint
        ind = np.random.choice(np.arange(self.n_obs))
      else:
        ind = np.argmax(self.min_distances)
      # New examples should not be in already selected since those points
      # should have min_distance of zero to a cluster center.
      assert ind not in already_selected

      self.update_distances([ind], only_new=True, reset_dist=False)
      new_batch.append(ind)
    print('Maximum distance from cluster centers is %0.2f'
            % max(self.min_distances))


    self.already_selected = already_selected

    return new_batch
```

I tried using the `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` function as well but that did not help with the OOM issues.

Is there a better way to find the minimum distance more efficiently wrt memory? The optimizations in the `scikit-learn` library has helped me in the past with time but it does not seem to be working on large datasets in this case.

Comment: Optimization can decrease the compute time it can't decrease the memory requirement. The total bytes required for storing the distance matrix would be `300000*300000*2` if you use `float16` precision. There is no way in which you can calculate the distance matrix of the entire dataset.

Comment: I agree. So the change that I am thinking of is to use chunks of data, find mimimums and just store those instead of the whole matrix. When I loop on the number of data points to compute this individually, it takes a really long time is all

Comment: If you try to decrease the space complexity of the code you have to compromise with the time complexity. I don't see any way other than chunking your dataset and iterating over it.

Comment: Gotcha, then chunking data it is. Thank you.